how to stop nextjs from combining all css modules into one css file in production?
I am currently working on optimizing Nextjs website for SEO. My styling option for the sites has been using css modules. I realized that Nextjs will combine all of them into one css file in production (after using next build). And this file is so large that it becomes a render-blocking resource when I check the site on pagespeed. I wonder if there is a way to stop Nextjs from merging all of the modules into one? Perhaps there is a way to override this behaviour using webpack config?
